# JSON.net Query list of JSON as if it's one

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have multiple JSON strings in a list. Although they all have different IDs and values, they all have the same structure.

Example JSON 1:

```
{
   "sold":true,
   "Stock":{
      "1":{
         "id":"11",
         "amount":"1",
      },
        "2":{
        "id":"12",
        "amount":"5",
      }
   },

   "Colors":{
      "11":{
         "RGB":"255,255,255",
      },
      "12":{
         "RGB":"0,0,0",
      }
   }
}
```

Example JSON 2:

```
{
   "sold":true,
   "Stock":{
      "3":{
         "id":"13",
         "amount":"2",
      },
        "4":{
        "id":"14",
        "amount":"1",
      }
   },

   "Colors":{
      "13":{
         "RGB":"0,0,255",
      },
      "14":{
         "RGB":"255,0,0",
      }
   }
}
```

In the end, I would like to parse all of them at once with something like this:

```
JObject JS = JObject.Parse(JSON);

string ID = JS.SelectToken("Stock.2.id").ToString;
string Color = JS.SelectToken("Colors." + ID + ".RGB").ToString;

return Color;
```

But for now, I would simply like a way to join "Stock" (Or "Colors") from JSON 1 and JSON 2 so that I can query them both together.

Comment: What is your desired result for given JSON?

Comment: "0,0,0". But the issue is that I wouldn't know weather to query "JSON 1", "JSON 2", or even "JSON 36". So I need to query them all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively what you have here is an *array* of objects, with that being the case, parse the data as such

```
string[] jsonObjs = new[] { JSON1, JSON2, ... };
string jsonArray = "[" + String.Join(", ", jsonObjs.ToArray()) + "]";
JArray arr = JArray.Parse(jsonArray);
```

Now you can query all the objects in the array in a single query, I'm not too familiar with JSON.NET but your query would look something along the lines of

```
string id = arr.Children<JObject>()
               .Single(x => x.SelectToken("Stock.2.id").ToString());
string color = arr.Children<JObject>()
                  .Where(x => x.SelectToken("Colors." + id) != null)
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.SelectToken("Colors." + id + ".RGB").ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use ToString() function with brackets:

```
JObject JS = JObject.Parse(JSON);

string ID = JS.SelectToken("Stock.2.id").ToString();
string Color = JS.SelectToken("Colors." + ID + ".RGB").ToString();

return Color;
```